# GRPC google storage golang CreateReadSession with rowRistriction contain subqueries

Tags: go, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Hello i'm using bigquery storage with grpc in golang , where i wanna get date from table data1.table1 with where condition (id not in (select id2 from data2.table2) but i got always same error that error while creating read session: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = request failed: Query error: Table not found: table2.data2 at [7:30] , but the table is there i can get data directly from it
any help please
I have all permission and all access once i remove  this id not in (select id2 from data2.table2)  from rowrestriction it works

This is my code

```
bqStorage "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/apiv1"
bqStoragepb "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery/storage/apiv1/storagepb"
func GetBQTable(client *bqStorage.BigQueryReadClient,
    projectID string,
    dataset string,
    table string,
    columns []string,
    rowRestriction string) ([]Data, error) {
    data := make([]Data, 0)

    ctx := context.Background()

    readTable := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/datasets/%s/tables/%s",
        projectID,
        dataset,
        table,
    )
    fmt.Println("rowRestriction", rowRestriction, readTable)

    tableReadOptions := &bqStoragepb.ReadSession_TableReadOptions{
        SelectedFields: columns,
        RowRestriction: rowRestriction,
    }

    dataFormat := bqStoragepb.DataFormat_ARROW

    createReadSessionRequest := &bqStoragepb.CreateReadSessionRequest{
        Parent: fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s", projectID),
        ReadSession: &bqStoragepb.ReadSession{
            Table:       readTable,
            DataFormat:  dataFormat,
            ReadOptions: tableReadOptions,
        },
        MaxStreamCount: 1,
    }

    fmt.Println("createReadSessionRequest", createReadSessionRequest)
    session, err := client.CreateReadSession(ctx, createReadSessionRequest, rpcOpts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error while creating read session: %v", err)
        if grpcErr, ok := status.FromError(err); ok {
            log.Printf("gRPC status code: %v", grpcErr.Code())
            log.Printf("gRPC status message: %v", grpcErr.Message())
            if details := grpcErr.Details(); len(details) > 0 {
                for _, d := range details {
                    log.Printf("gRPC details: %v", d)
                }
            }
        }
        return data, fmt.Errorf("error while creating read session: %w", err)
    }
    

    if len(session.GetStreams()) == 0 {
        return data, fmt.Errorf("no streams in session")
    }

    readStream := session.GetStreams()[0].Name

    ch := make(chan *bqStoragepb.ReadRowsResponse)


    return data, nil
}

``
```